# Clifford Algebra for understanding Atiyah Singer Index Theorem Reference Request

Tags: reference-request, differential-geometry, representation-theory, lie-algebras, clifford-algebras

I am interested in studying Atiyah Singer Index Theorem and Spin Geometry and would like to study Clifford Algebras and their representations for this purpose. I have a book 'Clifford Algebras : An introduction' by D.J.H. Garling. However I picked this book randomly and do not know if it is a good book. What are other standard references for this subject ? Would the material covered in Garling's book be sufficient algebraic background for study of Index Theorem and Spin Geometry ? I have some knowledge of graduate level algebra (Groups, Rings, Fields, Galois Theory, Commutative Algebra). Is it a good idea to study representation theory of Lie Groups and Lie Algebras say from Brian Hall's book before studying Clifford Algebras ?

Comment: Lawson and Michelson's _Spin Geometry_ contains enough material on Clifford algebras for someone learning spin geometry and index theory. You can also look at the first three lectures of the following notes: http://empg.maths.ed.ac.uk/Activities/Spin/SpinNotes.pdf

Comment: For the more algebraically inclined: http://carlossicoli.free.fr/M/Meinrenken_E.-Clifford_algebras_and_Lie_theory(December2012version)-Springer.pdf

Answer (score 5):

As mentioned above, *Spin Geometry* by Lawson and Michelson is a good reference. For those so inclined, I would also recommend the second edition of *Geometry, Topology and Physics* by Miko Nakahara, which devotes the last chapter to a proof of the Atiyah-Singer index theorem based on supersymmetric quantum mechanics.